# How do I center text in colored box with rounded corner with css

Tags: css, image, text, center, box

I´m trying to create an "image" with css to look like the real one (se attached .png) The size of the box is about 280x30 pix.

How do I do that?

Thanks for all help!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fI39A.png)

Comment: What have you actually tried?

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer please?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="box">
  Text Here
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.box {
  background: orange;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

Just adjust your widths, currently it's 100% wide.

Simples. https://jsfiddle.net/7ank4ueu/

Comment: Thanks Andy! Just what I needed.